# Get text separate by <br></br> inside TD tag using VBA

Tags: html, vba, excel, web-scraping

I get the TD tag using this code

```
Set TDElement = oHtml.getElementsByTagName("tr")(6).getElementsByTagName("td")(18)
```

This return me the whole text of the TD tag.

```
Text1
Text2
Text3
```

what I want to do, is to get each separately string before the `<br></br>`

This is the HTML page:

```
<td class="Td" nowrap="" valign="top">
  text1<br></br>
  text2<br></br>
  text3<br></br>
</td>
```

How to iterate over this strings inside the **TD** tag

Comment: replace <br> with nothing, and split by the </br> using the SPLIT function, or use the inner text

Comment: Thanks @Nathan_Sav that's work for me.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav: why don't you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: Btw the ```<br>``` tag is an empty tag which means that it has no end tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like....

```
    dim strSplit() as string
    dim intCounter as integer
    dim strSelection as string

    strHTML=replace(strHTML,"<br>","")
    strSplit=split(strHTML,"</br>")

    for intCounter=0 to ubound(strSplit)
        strSelection = strSplit(intCounter)
    next intCounter
```

Answer (score 1):

`br` is not an element of the HTML page and cannot be pointed to.

It means break (a new line).

So for your example, if you get `innerText` of this `td` tag like:

```
IE.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(**this td number**).innerText
```

you would get:

```
text1

text2

text3 (Note lines in between)
```

You would have to extract the inner Text of the `td` tag and use String manipulation to split into 3 strings using the line break as your separator.